# COUNT from 2 separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that have data that I need a count from

Login History
and
Login Attempts

One is a Login History table that does not include Login Attemtps.

The primary key of Login History is REF_ID, but also contains Customer_ID. The Login Attempts table's also includes Customer_ID

I'm trying to get a count of login attempts and login history for specific Customer_id's. I've gotten a list of Customer_ID's and placed them in a temporary table "#a"
Here's the query I'm trying to use to get this count.

```
SELECT COUNT (la.customer_ID) as login_attempts FROM
LOGIN_ATTEMPTS la
JOIN LOGIN_HISTORY lh
on la.Customer_ID = lh.customer_ID
where la.customer_ID in (select Customer_ID from #a)group by la.customer_ID
```

The result set I would need is the Customer_ID's, and the count for each Customer's login attempts and history next to it. I've tried a few different ways, and I always end up with errors with my GROUP BY or COUNT syntax.

I'm also assuming I could add a SUM function in here somewhere but I'm not sure how I would need to structure it. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on @bummi's second approach, without the additional subqueries:

```
Select customer_ID,
       sum(case when ltype = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as LoginAttempts,
       sum(case when ltype = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) as LoginHistory
from ((select 'A' as ltype, customer_ID
       from LOGIN_ATTEMPTS
      ) union all
      (select 'H' as ltype, customer_id
       from LOGIN_HISTORY
      ) 
     ) l
where customer_Id in (select Customer_Id from #A)
group by customer_Id
```

Comment: I tried running this one, and I get the error, "Column 'l.customer_id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 2):

```
Select customer_ID
,(Select Count(*) from LOGIN_ATTEMPTS l where l.customer_ID=a#.ID) as [LOGIN_ATTEMPTS]
,(Select Count(*) from LOGIN_HISTORY h where h.customer_ID=a#.ID) as [LOGIN_HISTORY]
from a#
```

and without the use of a#

```
Select customer_ID
,(Select Count(*) from LOGIN_ATTEMPTS l where l.customer_ID=a2.ID) as [LOGIN_ATTEMPTS]
,(Select Count(*) from LOGIN_HISTORY h where h.customer_ID=a2.ID) as [LOGIN_HISTORY]
( 
Select Distinct customer_ID from
(
select customer_ID from LOGIN_ATTEMPTS
union
select customer_ID from LOGIN_HISTORY
) a1
)a2
```

Comment: I like this one too since there are no JOIN's needed, and I can see which one was attempts and which one was a successful login. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT (*)  AS Attempts, 
   la.Customer_ID 
FROM
  LOGIN_ATTEMPTS la
JOIN 
   LOGIN_HISTORY lh
on la.Customer_ID = lh.customer_ID
where 
   la.customer_ID in (select Customer_ID from #a)
group by 
   la.customer_ID
```

Comment: You guys are awesome... I was close, I just need to better understand the COUNT function.

Comment: I'm surprised that you accepted this answer, since it will not return the correct results when a customer does not have exactly one record in Login_History.

Comment: I noticed that afterwards, but I ended up putting all records returned from this statement into another table and joined on both the LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, and LOGIN_HISTORY and received 5 more records.